# Wordpress Mod rewrite

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I am trying to add a rule to wordpress so that anything like /src/test becomes /src?urn=test with the following rule.

```
add_action('init', 'add_src_url');
function add_src_url()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^src/([^/]*)$',
        'src/urn=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Content of .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The above is not working. Mod Rewrite is enable. Is there any problem with the code ?

Comment: Did you flushed your rules?

Comment: yes, i did flush them with flush_rewrite_rules(); just after the above function

Comment: Then look in your htaccess - if rules has been flushed you should see your rule in top of the default WP rules. If so see if there is any syntax error.

Comment: where can I check the default WP Rules ?

Comment: Look into your .htaccess file and paste the content in your question.

Comment: Is my answer useful to you? If useful then please accept it and +vote....

Comment: @user1774937 The rule isn't added to the htaccess. It seems you dind't properly flushed your rules. Try to visit the permalinks settings page, and see if your htaccess has been updated.

Comment: not it hasn't been uupdated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below and let me know:

```
/* Add rewrite rule */

function hotel_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%{custom_data_var}%', '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^{custom_name}/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?pagename={page_name}&{custom_data_var}=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'hotel_add_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: You should not keep `flush_rewrite_rules()` in your `init` function - you can use it once to flush the rules, but as it is a very expensive operation you shouldn't call it at every page load. See [`flush_rewrite_rules`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) documentation. An other way to flush the rules safely is to visit the permalinks settings page.

Comment: @user1774937 Have  you save permalink again after add the same code?

Comment: Here it is: /*Noor codes*/
function hotel_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%{urn}%', '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^{src}/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?pagename={src}&{urn}=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'hotel_add_rewrite_rules');

Comment: @user1774937 `?pagename={src}` means, you have to wrrite the name of page `{src}` that means page slug.

Comment: oppps, yeah u right, i forgot this because my page slug is sca, quite similar

Comment: @user1774937 Your code is look like i.e. `add_rewrite_rule('^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=test-page-slug&custom_var=$matches[1]', 'top');`

Comment: the new codes, function hotel_add_rewrite_rules() { 
echo "test";
add_rewrite_tag('%{urn}%', '([^/]*)'); 
 add_rewrite_rule('^{sca}/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?pagename={sca}&{urn}=$matches[1]', 'top');
} 
add_action('init', 'hotel_add_rewrite_rules');

Comment: nopes, doesn't work, http://smartcities.tech/index.php?pagename=sca correct goes to the sca page but http://smartcities.tech/sca/project_0 gives me page can't be found. you can see it at http://smartcities.tech/sca/project_0

Comment: @user1774937 Have you remove `{ }`? and then save your permalink from wp-admin?